# Changing permissions for more than one role

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I just got into Python, and General programming and I already started with coding my own bots, but now I am having a problem with changing permissions with a bot command, to be more exact I want to Change the permissions for more than one role, here's what I got until know, and I know it's messy and all and I would very much appreciate some help!

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("botadmin")
async def giveperm(ctx, *rankName: str):
    rank = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name=' '.join(rankName))
    await bot.say("Give me a moment! Giving permissions to post in " + str(ctx.message.channel))
    perms = discord.PermissionOverwrite(send_messages=True)
for rankName in str(rank):
    await bot.edit_channel_permissions(channel=ctx.message.channel, target=rankName, overwrite=perms)
if ctx.message.channel == "suggestions":
    await bot.say("Suggestions are now open again for a week! \n\n Please only post suggestions here to prevent any chaos, with that said, have fun and happy suggesting!")
else:
    await bot.say("Permissions granted to " + rankName + " to post in " + str(ctx.message.channel))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`utils.get` will return a single `role` from `server.roles`.  Instead, we can use a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#discord-converters) to have `discord.py` give us the roles directly from parsing the command

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("botadmin")
async def giveperm(ctx, *roles: discord.Role):
    await bot.say("Give me a moment! Giving permissions to post in " + str(ctx.message.channel))
    perms = discord.PermissionOverwrite(send_messages=True)

    for role in roles:
        await bot.edit_channel_permissions(channel=ctx.message.channel, target=rankName, overwrite=perms)

    if ctx.message.channel == "suggestions":
        await bot.say("Suggestions are now open again for a week! \n\n Please only post suggestions here to prevent any chaos, with that said, have fun and happy suggesting!")
    else:
        await bot.say("Permissions granted to " + rankName + " to post in " + str(ctx.message.channel))
```

Comment: I will try it out later! Thanks for your quick answer! :)